# Remove "View Cart" link which appears after click on the "Add To Cart" button in WooCommerce

Tags: php, jquery, css, woocommerce, product

I am using Wordpress version 4.5.2 and WooCommerce version 2.5.5.

After clicking on the "Add To Cart" button, one link appears "View Cart".

Can anyone help me to remove that link?

Text to remove:

[image: Text to remove]

Comment: Depending on settings and customizations, to get some real help, please could you give us a link to your web site.

Answer (score 8):

Because this functionality is hard-baked into the JS of WooCommerce, you can't disable it with a filter or hook. However, after trawling through WC's code, I discovered a handy (and slightly hacky) caveat:

If you add the following empty div to the **same container as your *Add to Cart* button**, the `View Cart` (or `View Basket` if you're in the UK) link won't get added:

`<div class="added_to_cart"></div>`

This is because the Javascript file checks to see if an element with that class already exists:

```
// View cart text
if ( ! wc_add_to_cart_params.is_cart && $thisbutton.parent().find( '.added_to_cart' ).size() === 0 ) {
    $thisbutton.after( ' <a href="' + wc_add_to_cart_params.cart_url + '" class="added_to_cart wc-forward" title="' +
        wc_add_to_cart_params.i18n_view_cart + '">' + wc_add_to_cart_params.i18n_view_cart + '</a>' );
}
```

If it finds an existing `.added_to_cart` element, it won't try to append another.

It's worth noting that [Sathyanarayanan G's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37436996/988246) should totally work too (and I'm surprised it didn't - that sort of points to something else being wrong), but in a slightly different way.

Comment: How this can be hard-baked is beyond comprehension. Thank you, you saved me some time, i was assuming woocommerce developers had some brain.

Answer (score 4):

I think this may be useful.

Just add this code in css.

```
a.added_to_cart.wc-forward {display:none}
```

Comment: I have added an image of text that i want to remove.

Answer (score 4):

Adding the below line of code to your child theme's style.css should do the trick.

```
a.added_to_cart {display:none !important}
```

Answer (score 2):

That will do the job (but its not the ideal solution)

```
// Removes Product Successfully Added to Cart
// Woocommerce 2.1+

add_filter( 'wc_add_to_cart_message', 'wc_custom_add_to_cart_message' );

function wc_custom_add_to_cart_message() {
    echo '<style>.woocommerce-message {display: none !important;}</style>';
}
```

Comment: I have added an image of text that i want to remove.

Comment: You need to check your theme, and what's that message parent div, then replace in the code above.

Comment: That message comes via ajax. If I hide it then other function doesn't work. Like if I add above code then mini cart subtotal doesn't change after click on Add To Cart button.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to keep the "Add To Cart" button and remove the "View Basket"

```
// Makes "Add to Cart" button visible again
.add_to_cart_button.added  {display:  inline-block}
// Removes "View Basket"
.added_to_cart.wc-forward {display: none}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is code for change name of **view cart button text** and **change button URL**.

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme). Tested and works.

```
function change_view_cart( $params, $handle )
{
    switch ($handle) {
        case 'wc-add-to-cart':
            $params['i18n_view_cart'] = "Proceed to Cart"; //chnage Name of view cart button
            $params['cart_url'] = "http://shop.com/cart"; //change URL of view cart button
        break;
    }
    return $params;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_script_data', 'change_view_cart',10,2 );
```

Please do not change any code into the **add-to-cart.js** file.
Otherwise its not work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Adding this to style.css in child theme worked for me.

```css
body .dhvc-woo-addtocart a.added_to_cart {
    display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for not having explanation. Add to functions.php the following lines

```
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'no_view_cart' );
function no_view_cart() {
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery( function($){

    $(document.body).on( 'added_to_cart', function( event, fragments, cart_hash, $button ) {
        $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: wc_add_to_cart_params.ajax_url,
                data: {
                    'action': 'checking_items',
                    'id'    : $button.data( 'product_id' )
                },
                success: function (response) {

                    $button.removeClass( 'added' );
                    $button.parent().find( '.added_to_cart' ).remove();

                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
<?php
}
```

Other thing not related to this OP question. If you want to remove the "View Cart" button *after* item(s) has been removed from mini cart, you can add another jQuery function, but this should not be placed in no_view_cart() function:

```
$('.button[data-product_id="' + product_id + '"]').removeClass( 'added' );
$('.button[data-product_id="' + product_id + '"]').parent().find( '.added_to_cart' ).remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

I come very late to the coding "fiesta"…

The following will first hide "view cart" button (via CSS), then with jQuery, I remove it, and remove also "added" class from Ajax add to cart button:

```php
add_action('wp_head', 'ajax_added_to_cart_js', 99999);
function ajax_added_to_cart_js() {
    if( ( is_woocommerce() && ! is_account_page() ) || is_cart() ) :
    // Removing "View cart" button and "added" class.
    wc_enqueue_js("$('body').on('added_to_cart', function(){
        setTimeout( function(){
            $('a.ajax_add_to_cart').each( function(i){
                if ( $(this).hasClass('added') ) {
                    $(this).removeClass('added').parent().find('a.added_to_cart.wc-forward').remove();
                }
            });
        }, 5 );
    });");
    ?>
    <style>.added_to_cart.wc-forward{display:none;}</style>
    <?php endif;
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your child theme (or in a plugin).